# Problems with user features with Jtwitter

Tags: java, search, status, jtwitter

My code is :

```
     List<Status> list = new ArrayList<Status>();
     User user;
     Twitter twitter = new Twitter();       
     list = twitter.search(string); 

    for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++){
        user=list.get(i).getUser();
        System.out.print(i+1);
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getId());
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getUser());
        System.out.println(user.getId());
        System.out.println(user.getCreatedAt());
        System.out.println(user.getLocation());
        System.out.println(user.getFavoritesCount());
    }
```

The problem is that good print the status, id of status and user, but user features how user id, location, etc, prints all as null. What I can do to take the features????

Thanks for response

Comment: I tried to answer your question, but couldn't find a question mark, or a sentence structured as a question. I am so, so sorry.

Comment: Without knowing the code for `user.get***()` methods, we can't tell why they are returning null.

Comment: they are all default methods jtwitter

Comment: FinnLarsen the class user is one class for deafult in jtwitter

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JTwitter API Docs](http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter/javadoc/winterwell/jtwitter/Twitter.html), calling the default constructor creates a new instance **without a user**. You need to authenticate with Twitter using `Twitter.IHttpClient` (which depends on [Signpost](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/)) to get user data.

Answer (score 0):

The Twitter search method is unusual in that it only returns a small part of the User information. This is a limitation from Twitter & there's nothing you can do about that.

Fields such as location will be blank.

You always get the screen-name, and this can be used to fetch the extra info via the show() method. E.g.

```
Twitter twitter;
List<String> userNames; // make this list from user.screenName
List<User> fullUserInfo = twitter.users().show(userNames)
```

If you have an up-to-date copy of JTwitter (http://www.winterwell.com/software/jtwitter.php) it is all in the javadoc.

NB: Other methods sometimes return missing fields in User, if Twitter is experiencing heavy load.